# Recline JS - Grid shows Headings but not the Data

Tags: javascript

So I'm attempting to use Recline. I've followed the tutorial and I can get the grid to show the headings but it doesn't show the data within I currently have:

```
var data = [
    {id: 0, date: '2011-01-01', x: 1, y: 2, z: 3, country: 'DE', geo: {lat:52.56, lon:13.40} },
    {id: 1, date: '2011-02-02', x: 2, y: 4, z: 24, country: 'UK', geo: {lat:54.97, lon:-1.60}},
    {id: 2, date: '2011-03-03', x: 3, y: 6, z: 9, country: 'US', geo: {lat:40.00, lon:-75.5}},
    {id: 3, date: '2011-04-04', x: 4, y: 8, z: 6, country: 'UK', geo: {lat:57.27, lon:-6.20}},
    {id: 4, date: '2011-05-04', x: 5, y: 10, z: 15, country: 'UK', geo: {lat:51.58, lon:0}},
    {id: 5, date: '2011-06-02', x: 6, y: 12, z: 18, country: 'DE', geo: {lat:51.04, lon:7.9}}
    ];

            var dataset = new recline.Model.Dataset({
                records: data
            });
            var $el = $('#mygrid');
            var grid = new recline.View.SlickGrid({
                model: dataset,
                el: $el
            });
            grid.visible = true;
            grid.render();
```

And I have all of the dependencies they list in the tutorial. I was wondering what could be causing this to not work as expected?

Answer (score -1):

try css

```
    .recline-slickgrid 
    {
      height: 500px;
    }
```